# TeamCity build multiple projects from a single solution into different build pipelines

Tags: teamcity

I am a little new to TeamCity and devOps on the whole. I have a .net core solution with multiple API projects and a xunit test project all sitting in one repo.

In teamcity I am able to setup a build pipeline to build the projects by giving the path to the .csproj, however the problem is if I make any change in one api project all other projects also get a build even though there is no code change in them.

In addition, even the test project runs all tests instead of just the tests that was changed for a given API.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can get this to work?